# recover variable for use in a modal

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

I have a small problem, I have to use the modal for 24 different cases, I have to get an id before going into the modal to test this id with the modal id and display the result in the modal. I do not know if I expressed well! but here is the code

```js
 <!-- Modal -->
                <?php
                $x=7;
                $case = $fun -> getCaseByIde($x);
                ?>
                <div id="myModal-<?php echo $x; ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h1><?php echo $x; $case['titre']; ?></h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- #END# Modal -->
                <!-- Modal -->
                <?php
                $x=8;
                $case = $fun -> getCaseByIde($x);
                ?>
                <div id="myModal-<?php echo $x; ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h1><?php echo $x; $case['titre']; ?></h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- #END# Modal -->
                <!-- Modal -->
                <?php
                $x=9;
                $case = $fun -> getCaseByIde($x);
                ?>
                <div id="myModal-<?php echo $x; ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h1><?php echo $x; $case['titre']; ?></h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- #END# Modal -->
```

Comment: In English, please.

Comment: Hello, I have a small problem, I have to use the modal for 24 different cases, I have to get an id before going into the modal to test this id with the modal id and display the result in the modal. I do not know if I expressed well! but here is the code

Comment: Please edit your question with your additional information for a better overview, instead of adding as comment ;)

Comment: ok i will ,  thankyou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're manually creating all your 24 modals?

Try using a **for loop**:

```
<?php
$modalCount = 24; // Number of modals you want to create. (Nombre de modals à créer)

// Create a modal from 0 to 23. (Créer un modal de 0 à 23)
// Use "$x = 1" and "$x <= $modalCount" if you want from 1 to 24. (Utilise ... si tu veux de 1 à 24)
for ($x = 0 ; $x < $modalCount ; $x++): ?>

<!-- Modal -->
<?php $case = $fun->getCaseByIde($x); ?>

<div id="myModal-<?php echo $x; ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h1><?php echo $x; $case['titre']; ?></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- #END# Modal -->

<?php endfor; ?>
```

If it is not your problem, please, be more precise.

Comment: yes the problem is resolved !! thankyou very much for your help siir